# How to embed an inline script to an HTML page instead of a JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, embed

I want to append some JavaScript to another page (any other page that allows it), but I want the code inline and not as another JS-file.

This one works, but then I'm stuck with a static JS-file, and I need to add a variable to it.

```html
<a href="javascript: (function () {var bookmarklet = document.createElement('script'); bookmarklet.setAttribute('src', 'https://example.com/bookmarklet/index.js'); document.body.appendChild(bookmarklet); }());">Bookmarklet</a>
```

Do I need to do something like `document.write` instead of `document.createElement`, or should I switch `scr` with `text`?

Comment: Thanks, seems `script.text  = "alert('voila!');"` should work. I'll check and mark it as duplicate / solution.